# What is the Curie temperature of iron within the Earth's outer core?

Tags: electromagnetism, pressure, temperature, geophysics

According to Wikipedia, Curie temperature is affected by pressure:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature#Pressure

If my understanding is correct, since the liquid iron in the outer core is responsible for generating the Earth's magnetic field, the pressure must be high enough to raise the Curie temperature above the temperature of the outer core.

According to Wikipedia:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth's_outer_core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_outer_core)

> Estimates for the temperature of the outer core are about 3,000–4,500 K (2,730–4,230 °C; 4,940–7,640 °F) in its outer region and 4,000–8,000 K (3,730–7,730 °C; 6,740–13,940 °F) near the inner core.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> If my understanding is correct, since the liquid iron in the outer core is responsible for generating the Earth's magnetic field, the pressure must be high enough to raise the Curie temperature above the temperature of the outer core.

No, that's not right - the magnetic field isn't generated because the outer core is magnetized.  It's the fact that the outer core is electrically conductive, allowing it to act as a [magnetic dynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_theory).